# I have a problem with migration as I am new to Laravel. I have tried everything described on here with no success

Tags: laravel, xampp

I am new to Laravel. I have MAMP and Xampp 7.3.0 installed on my MacOS Mojave but currently using Xampp on port 80 with MySQL port reconfigured to 33060 as phpmyadmin wasn't working. 
I have a problem with "php artisan migrate" as the following error displays each time I am trying to migrate:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = land
  on_app and table_name = migrations
```

)

I have tried to search online, adopted the suggested solutions by contributors but none seems to work for me. I have tried to install MySQL 8.0.13, but I encountered caching_sha2_password which prompted me to uninstall it and installed MySQL5.7 with a displayed version message "**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper**"
However, I decided to copy the folder to httdoc and reconfigured my .env.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=landon_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '33060'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'landon_app'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,


        ],
```

AppServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //This must be added 


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //This must be added to allow connection to the database
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The error I receive each time I try to migrate:

Comment: Facing the same issue on laravel 5.8 `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ekm-parcel2G and table_name = migrations)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line in your `.env` file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

To

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
  have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corr
  esponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
  to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `reservations` a
  dd constraint `reservations_client_id_foreign` foreign key (
  `client_id`) references `clients` ())

Comment: So, That means now your connection is okay. But you have another error when you try to update your reservations table.

Comment: I need your migration file to solved that issue. Best you can search stackoverflow. there are many solution available regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it. I made a mistake instead of "   $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');" , I wrote "   $table->foreign('client_id')->reference('id')->on('clients');"

Answer (score 0):

Start with few simple debugging steps: 
- Can you access your mysql server with provided credentials? 
- Can you verify that the database named 'landon_app' exist on ur server? 
- You can also try changing host from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4: Change "host" in the app/config/database.php file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Laravel 5: Change "DB_HOST" in the .env file from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"